# How to correctly display the numbers for each table row added

Tags: jquery

I have a slight problem with my application. What is suppose to happen is that when the user selects an option and answer and submits it, it will add a new row. The problem is that the question number is suppose to be +1 every time a new row is created so that it goes question number 1 for row 1, question number 2 for row 2 and etc. Instead it is just displaying the number 1 for each row under the question number column.

How can I get it to display 1,2,3 etc for the question No for each row added.

To use the jsfiddle app do this:

open grid and select option "3", type in the number 1 in the "Number of Answers" text-box and select Button "A". Then click on "Add Question" and a new row is added.

"qnum" in the insertQuestion(form) function controls the question number and the insertQuestion(from) function can be found near the bottom of the javascript code and this function adds the new rows in the table.

Code is in jsfiddle, click [here](http://jsfiddle.net/YTh5Y/4/)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were missing an opening `<form>` tag

forked fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ubS6c/

Comment: Is it ok if I asked where you made the change?

Comment: @user1050384 Very first line of the HTML frame.  I just added a parameter-less `<form>` tag to the top.

Comment: Oh wait a minute, so if I have form tag then it works, if I don't then it doesn't work, but I do have a <form> tag I just forgot to add it in my jsfiddle, my form tag is in my updated jsfiddle in my question

Comment: Oh no my form tag from my app does work in jsfiddle, let me check my app again, give me 1 minute

Comment: Ok I know why it was not working. In my jsfidde my var qnum = 1; was outside the insertQuestion(form) function while in my application it is inside the function. Problem is fixed though. I will mark your answer. Thank You and thanks to everybody else for attempting to answer my question :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
var qnum = $('#qandatbl').find("tr").length - 1;
```

Comment: Hi, if I do that then it displays all the question numbers as "0".

Answer (score 0):

You can count the number of elements with a particular class as follows:

```
var qnum = jQuery('.qid').length;
var html = jQuery("<tr><td class='qid'>" + qnum + "</td></tr>");
```

Notes:

- did you look at jqgrid? http://www.trirand.com/blog/

Typically I would solve this sort of thing with jqgrid and ajax call-backs. Some logical back-end can then be used to do more of the calculation, separating out the separation of interaction, view, control and domain.